# How do I prevent rpmbuild form injecting requirements into RPM package?

Tags: python, rpmbuild

I'm creating an RPM package from native Python 2.5 one. Out corporate policy is to use python2.4 by default, so I'm adding a string

```
Requires: python25
```

to a [.spec file](http://pastebin.com/m70f162fc). When I look at created RPM file though, i see the following dependencies:

```
rpm -qR -p ZSI-2.1_a1-py25.noarch.rpm
/usr/bin/python2.5
python(abi) = 2.5
python25  
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
```

Dependency added by me is present, but other dependencies are also here.
I'm unable to provide  python(abi) = 2.5 dependency, because of dumb python25 package generated by our IT department where provides tag is incorrect.

How do I remove automatically added dependencies from generated RPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it up afterwards with [rpmrebuild](http://rpmrebuild.sourceforge.net/):

rpmrebuild --package --edit-requires ZSI-2.1_a1-py25.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 7):

You can turn off automatic dependency processing in the .spec with:

```
AutoReqProv: no
```

http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html

Comment: Link is broken, good link is http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html

Comment: For newer versions and more fine grained control over Python abi and dependencies only, use `%undefine __pythondist_requires` and `%undefine __python_requires`.